# JAWS reads aria-label multiple times for a table with role="img", in MS Edge on Win10

Tags: wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

I have a `table` element that contains an HTML bar chart, and I want screen readers to read a text description of it, so I'm using this approach:

```
 <table role="img" aria-label="table description">
```

In Voiceover on Mac, it reads the label and skips over the rest of the content in the table. However in JAWS with MS Edge on Windows 10 it reads "graphic table description" for each `td` in the table, and in nested tables too. Here's a simplified example:

```
    <table role="img" aria-label="table description">
        <tr>
            <td>
                row 1
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                row 2
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

This problem doesn't happen with IE 11 on the same Windows computer; it reads "graphic table description" just *once*.

I also tried adding `aria-hidden="true"`, `tabindex="-1"`, and `role="presentation"` to the `td` and `tr` elements in the table, but none of those helped.

Am I doing this wrong? Is there a better way to achieve this? I'm wondering if this is a bug in JAWS...

Comment: Are you using a <table> and CSS to create a bar chart?  That is, the table is more for structuring your bar chart and it's not really a table with rows and columns and table cells and column headers?  Similar to how tables are sometimes used for layout purposes, to get things to line up nicely in columns, but there's really not a table of information display.  Just trying to understand your use of tables.  The first thing that popped into my mind regarding your code sample was the 2nd rule of ARIA use - https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#second

Comment: Yeah @slugolicious I'm using this `<table>` for layout (not data) purposes, since this chart is an email and some older emails clients (especially MS Outlook) don't support divs and modern css styling very well. Since it wouldn't make sense for the screen reader to read anything in the table, I'm using `role="img"` and giving it an `aria-label` to read instead.

Comment: The _actual_ `<table>` has several nested tables in it, to render a bar chart with labels and proper spacing. It's unfortunate to be using `tables` for layout and styling purposes like in the year 2019, but unfortunately that's what it takes to support older (but still widely used) email clients.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from the comment section to the answer section because this might be a solution (and is too long to put in the comment).

> The *actual* `<table>` has several nested tables in it

Ah, that could be part of the problem. If you use `<table role="presentation">`, the "presentation" status only conveys to table child elements (`<thead>, <tbody>, <tfoot>, <tr>, <th>, <td>`) but **stops** if it hits a nested table. The nested table would *also* need `role="presentation"`.

If you apply that same logic to using `role="img"`, the nested table would **not** be seen as an image and would, in fact, cause invalid html because an `<img>` cannot have any child DOM elements.  `role="img"` on the outer table would make the entire table an image, so the nested `<thead>, <tbody>, <tfoot>, <tr>, <th>, <td>` elements would all be ignored, but once a nested `<table>` is seen, then you'd have problems.

I'm not sure if the following would be valid:

```
<table role="img" aria-label="chart description">
  <!-- other table stuff -->

  <!-- nested table -->
  <table role="presentation">
  </table>
</table>
```

The outer table would be an image and the inner table should be ignored, but you'd still have an element (inner table) inside an image.  You'd have to run it through an [html parser checker](https://html5.validator.nu/).

In addition to `role="presentation"` on the inner table, you could also add `aria-hidden="true"` to hide the table from screen readers, otherwise a screen reader user could navigate all the text elements (if any) inside the "presentation" table.

Comment: > the "presentation" status only conveys to table child elements (...) but *stops* if it hits a nested table.

Ah, ok I didn't know that, thank you! It's funny you mention adding `role="presentation"` and `aria-hidden="true"` to inner tables, because I have tried adding those attributes to _all_ inner elements (as well as `tabindex=-1`) to see if they would fix it, but they did not.

Comment: That said, I think the problem is simpler than this and doesn't require addressing inner tables, because it happens even with with the trivial two row, one column table that I put in the question.